# Python REST API date format

Tags: python, api, rest

I am working on a Python REST API project where I need to retrieve data from a database. the database table has timestamp column since the data needs to be record many times per day. Here is a part of the code below.

In this piece of code, I need the API to show me the data of the current day (instead of a certain date).

```
import requests
import datetime

# Using python requests library, set up GET request
payload = {'date1' : 'CURDATE()', 'date2' : 'CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY'}

# Send GET request to REST API
r = requests.get('http://localhost:8080/data', params=payload)

# Decode the JSON result of the GET request
rows = r.json()

# Loop through data and format the date string
for i in rows:
    i[0] = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(i[0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print rows
```

In date1 and date 2 part, I used to use a certain date like 2013-12-30 and 2013-12-31, the program will return all the data from 2013-12-30. Right now when I try to ask the program to return whatever the data from the current day, the program gives me a blank result `[]`.

The code needs to talk to a database, but I doubt the problem comes from the database part. Hope everyone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: `CURDATE` is an SQL function. Is the database calling this to get the current date? Wouldn't it be easier to generate the current date in Python and send in a date string like you were before?

Comment: What exactly is REST about having a page named "data" that apparently takes arbitrary parameters that tell it what data to dynamically generate?

Comment: @Chris is right. If passing `CURDATE()` or `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` through your web service directly to the database actually worked, that would imply a serious bug in your web service (allowing for trivial SQL injection attacks).

Comment: @Chris, here is what I did. Since I import datetime from Python, I used `payload = {'date1' : 'datetime.date.today()', 'date2' : '2014-1-2'}`. date1 is whatever the current date, I set date2 to be Jan 2, 2014 since we are not there yet so there won't be any data show up and ideally I need date2 to be the next day of date1.

Comment: Yeah you guys are correct on CURDATE(). I shouldn't use it. But Python actually is able to compile this. It's just giving me blank `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Generate your dates in your Python code instead of passing arbitrary SQL functions to your database for execution, which is very dangerous.

```
>> import datetime
>> today = datetime.date.today()
>> tomorrow = today + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
>> print today
2013-12-31
>> print tomorrow
2014-01-01
```

Now you can pass `today` and `tomorrow` as date strings (e.g. `str(today)` or `'{0}'.format(today)` to your web service.

As noted in the comments, your service is not RESTful. You may want to read up on REST before going much further.

Comment: I understand the code you show here. But when I use date1 = datetime.date.today(), it gives me every piece of record since the day the database was created.

Comment: @ShuruiLiu, then you have a problem with your web service. You haven't shown us how it's meant to work, or any of its code, so we can't help you fix it.